# How to make an Edit check only change status with double click

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a gridview and a repositorycheckedit column, I want it to change its value only when it is double-clicked, and prevent it from changing with a single click.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this in the following way:

1. Make the column read-only.  This will disable the native behavior of allowing a click to edit the value.

   `colCheck.OptionsColumn.Readonly = true;`
2. Add an in-place repository item of a check box and assign it to the column.  If this column is a boolean, this is normally unnecessary (check is the default control type for a boolean), but this will help for the next step
3. Fire the double-click event on the repository item and alter the check property as follows:

~

```
private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo f = gridView1.GetFocusedRow() as Foo;
    f.Check = !f.Check;
    gridView1.RefreshData();
}
```

Let me know if that helps.